# Using new state in a function after setting it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

Can I use the updated state in the same function where it was updated?
With the example below, I get 0.

With `useEffect` I can access the new state right after setting the state, but how can I access it in the function?

As a side question, can I (or should I) use the state for situations when it is not directly connected to what is in the return? Should I use props instead?

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const handleClick = async () => {
    setCount(count => (count + 1));
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    console.log(count); // I get 0
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}></Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You are logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/#32-usestate) Instead you can do something like this: `const newCount = count+1; setCount(newCount); await someAsync(); console.log(newCount)`

Comment: @HMR You should not set the state based on the old state without using the callback form of set state. State is asynchronous, so this will lead to bugs and weird behaviour.

Comment: @ViktorW `You should not set the state based on the old state without using the callback` You are [wrong](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) (first code block). In this case `handleClick` is re created when count changes so there is no stale closure when doing `setCount(count+1)` or `newCount = count+1`

Comment: @HMR But if you click the button twice, really fast, the count would only increase once, since it takes a little bit of time before the new render, right?

Comment: No it won't, you may have some wonky behaviour when you want to set other state based on newCount after async but state will be fine. See first block of code in React documentation I posted earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot (or perhaps you can with a little bit of trickery as I'll show you). With functional components, state is a little bit different. Your handleClick function gets created when the component renders, and because of how JavaScript works, it gets attached to the "scope" of that particular render. Even after the timeout, it is still in that old scope.

One way to solve this could be to use a ref.

```
function App() { 
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    const countRef = useRef(count)
    countRef.current = count

    const handleClick = async () => {
        setCount(count => (count + 1)); 
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000)); 
        console.log(countRef.current); 
    } 

    return ( 
        <div>
            <Button onClick={handleClick}></Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This will update the ref when the component is re-rendered. This update will change all refs, even the ones in the old scopes.

However, I use React quite a lot and I am certain that I have never been required to use this in practice. I'd say it's bad practice: even with a timeout, you cannot be 100% certain that the state has actually have had enough time to update, so this could lead to weird bugs. Why would you actually want to do this? Can't you instead put your code that requires the new state in an useEffect for example?

As for the side-question: You should use state when you need to re-render the component whenever the state changes. If you do not want your component to re-render when the state changes, you should use another method of storing the data (for example refs).

Comment: Thank you, for your answer! Forgot to mention, but only used timeout in the example to see if the problem is with time that it requires to change the state.
I analyse a video frame by frame (well not frame by frame exactly but with skips) and on each frame, I set the state with the new data gained from the current frame and draw something on the canvas. I guess I dont have to store that in the state.

Answer (score 1):

You just can’t. That a reason why I use useReducer.